# DotNetCoreCLI@2 Azure DevOps Task not adding handlers to web.config unless zipAfterPublish is true

Tags: .net-core, iis, azure-pipelines, web-config, web.config-transform

I'm currently working with an ASP.NET Core application and setting up a CI/CD pipeline using Azure DevOps. As part of my deployment strategy, I'm trying to generate a `web.config` file with the correct handlers added during the `publish` process, but without actually zipping the published output. I need to do this because I want to frequently update just the `web.config` file in my deployment, without requiring a full redeployment of the application.

I have created a separate publish profile with the `WebPublishMethod` set to `FileSystem`, as I do not want to deploy the entire solution, just the `web.config` file. Here's the portion of my publish profile:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <!-- Rest of config -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And here is a portion of my pipeline setup:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNet Build
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    zipAfterPublish : false
    projects: '${{parameters.project}}'
    arguments: '-c Release -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output
        /p:PublishProfile=${{parameters.publishProfile}}'
```

In this setup, I noticed that the `handlers` are not added to the `web.config` file. However, if I change `zipAfterPublish` to `true`, the `handlers` are correctly added. Here's the pipeline setup with `zipAfterPublish` set to `true`:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNet Build
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    zipAfterPublish : true
    projects: '${{parameters.project}}'
    arguments: '-c Release -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/output
        /p:PublishProfile=${{parameters.publishProfile}}'
```

My goal is to have the correct `web.config` file generated without zipping the output, because my application's deployment strategy involves frequently updating the `web.config` file, without requiring a full redeployment of the application. For speed and efficiency, I'd like to keep the output unzipped so that I can easily replace the `web.config` file.

When the `zipAfterPublish` is set to `true` and I unzip the build output I can see the headers in the `web.config`

```xml
<handlers>
   <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\some_site.Website.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

But when its set to `false` they are not present in the `web.config`

Does anyone have insights on why the `handlers` are not added when `zipAfterPublish` is set to `false`? Any advice on how these `handlers` are set and where they come from would be really nice.